# When is a filepath neccessary using pandas when working with an excel file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, filepath

I am trying to get into pandas and I am confused here is a program that reads from an excel file and it works without giving it a filepath when the excel file is in the same folder as the python program:

```
import pandas as pd

excel_file = "RandomExcelNumbers.xlsx"
xldata = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name= "Sheet1")

xl_Value1 = xldata["ColTitle2"][0]
print(xl_Value1)
```

Now I tried something different:

```
import pandas as pd

filename = "Test.xlsx"

def read_value_from_excel(filename, column="C", row=3):
    """Read a single cell value from an Excel file"""
    return pd.read_excel(filename, skiprows=row - 1, usecols=column, nrows=1, header=None, names=["Value"]).iloc[0]["Value"]

print(read_value_from_excel(filename, "C", 3))
```

and it gives me this error message: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Test.xlsx'`

Please, what's the difference between these two programs? One needs the filepath, the other does not? Why is that? Is there a way to not neccessarily give the filepath in program no. 2 and let the program compile?

Thank you!

Comment: Is Test.xls.in the same folder as your script? Python will check in the current working directory, if it isn't there then you need to give the file path to where the file is located.

Comment: You're using a path in both cases - a relative path. Either the code executes in the wrong folder or the file is missing.  Relative paths are relative to the current working folder. Use `os.getcwd()` or `pathlib.Path.cwd()` to find out what the current working folder is

Comment: This has nothing to do with Excel or Pandas. Using hard-coded relative paths is brittle. Pass around the path to the file as an argument, preferably as a `Path`. Validate the file location when you read the path from configuration or user input. `Path` makes this easier. Convert relative paths to absolute as soon as possible using `Path.resolve()` to avoid errors if your own application changes its working directory

Comment: Ok.... I found the issue.... i named the excel file:
"Test.xlsx"
but  ".xlsx" was also automatically added to the file. So the file's name was:
"Test.xlsx.xlsx"